# error in node.js - connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mysql, node.js, cpanel

I am work on app where I must connect my app with database on some server. I have a problem with connecting my app to database on server (cPanel). In my file server.js I have this code

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql'); //npm install mysql
var rp = require('request-promise');  // npm install --save request-promise
var request = require('request'); //npm install --save request

let router = require("express").Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var apiRoutes = express.Router();

apiRoutes.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Node works' });
})

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "1.222.333.444",
  user: "dbuser",
  password: "qwertz",
  port: 3306, 
  database: "dbtest"
});

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
 if (err) {
    console.error("Error:  " + err);
 }
 else {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
 }
});
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Api works');
```

I start app with nodemon and I get this error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried watching firewall on the mysql machine ? When this error occurs, this oftently because the MySQL server did not accept the TCP connection

Comment: Maybe the mysql server instance did not access remote connection too. Try to check these points

Comment: I get this reply from provider of server I don't know your exact use-case but you should be able to connect to it using the credentials which you used when creating the database. If you're connecting from the same server to the database, use localhost as the host. If you're connecting remotely, then use the server IP as the host.